# Tableview multiple Parse queries and constraints in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview, uitableview

My first iOS app needs to proceed several Parse calls to populate a tableview with custom tableviewcell. I can't get my head around this approach. I hope someone is familiar with such a Parse task.
I query only one class:
The class object contains the attributes 'category', 'image', 'likes' and 'location'. 8 categories are given.
My goal is to fill a table view with the given categories where each cell displays an image of the most liked object of each individual category within a geoPoint distance. A placeholder image is shown if category does not contain objects. I would also use PFTableView subclass but I don't know how I can make all these queries work in queryForTable().

Updated:

```
private func queryCategories() {

    let entry = homeCategories.categories
    self.categoryArray.removeAllObjects()
    self.overallCount = 0

    let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    loadingNotification.labelText = Constants.Notifications.LoadingNotificationText

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) in

        for (index, cat) in entry.enumerate() {
            let query = Tip.query()
            query!.whereKey("category", equalTo: entry[index].category)
            query!.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint!, withinMiles: self.miles)
            query!.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (count: Int32, error: NSError?) in
                if (error == nil) {
                    print("\(index): \(cat)")
                    let number = Int(count)
                    entry[index].tipCount = number
                    self.overallCount += number

                }
                else {
                    NSLog("Count request failed - no objects found")
                }
            })

            let categoryQuery = Tip.query()
            categoryQuery!.whereKey("category", equalTo: entry[index].category)
            categoryQuery!.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint!, withinMiles: self.miles)
            categoryQuery!.orderByDescending("likes")
            categoryQuery!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) in
                if (error == nil) {

                    if let object = object {
                        self.categoryArray.addObject(object)
                    }
                    self.doTableRefresh()

                }
                else {
                    self.categoryArray.addObject(entry[index])
                    self.doTableRefresh()
                }
                loadingNotification.hide(true)
            })
        }
    }

}

private func doTableRefresh() {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}
```

I'm not sure about this approach. It actually works but shows some weird behaviour. It seems there is an issue with for loop and reloading table (because of asynchronism?).  Queries are not compliant as each try brings up different results. Thanks for any help!

Comment: stackoverflow is for helping people with bugs, nobody will create the code for you! What you are asking is on Google, I learned it from there, I would recommend using just UITableView instead of PFTableView though...

Comment: Thanks for your advice! All I asked for is advice for the best approach to deal with several queries because I can't find any similar issue on the web, not for code at all. I will post my code later on.

Comment: As an aside, isn't Parse shutting down in the near future? Not that it's super relevant to your question, but if you want your app to stick around for a while that might be something to consider.

Comment: You should tell where you are having problems with your code.

Comment: I'm just not sure about the queries within the for loop. Results are confused as they bring up different counts and images sometimes.

Comment: For example, the index in for loop starts at 4 randomly. But I need the for loop to iterate through the categories to get the first object of each.